# In node using modules. how to change require to import for stripe

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, stripe-payments

In my node application iam usign the modules system which i specified in my package file

```
 {
  "name": "ccbill-node-integration",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "node integration for ccbill",
  "main": "ppayproc1.js",
  "type": "module",
.....
```

this allows me to declare somnething like import express from ... instead of require.

iam working on stripe integration. as per their docs

const stripe = require('stripe')('sk_test_51_secretkey');

whats the equivalent of this using import.

i was thingking i can do something like

```
 import stripe from 'stripe';
    stripe('sk_test_51_secretkey');
```

will this be considered valid ?

thank you

Comment: See: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node?tab=readme-ov-file#usage

Answer (score 1):

Try the following, replacing `your_secret_key` with the key created via Stripes dashboard.

```
import Stripe from 'stripe';
const stripe = new Stripe('your_secret_key')
```